# c++ global variable usage

Tags: c++, c++14

What I'm trying to do:

```
//a.hpp

extern std::condition_variable m_condvar;
class A{
  ...
  
  };


//a.cpp
void A::func()
{
  if (condition)
  m_condvar.notify_all();
}
...


//main.cpp
...

std::condition_variable m_condvar;
while(1){
  if (m.condvar.wait_until(uLock, timePoint) == std::cv_status::timeout){
     break;
  }
}
```

My question is if this is the right way to define `m_condvar` (extern in `a.hpp`, declare it in `main.cpp`)? Is there any better way to do it?

updates:

```
class A{
  ...
  public:
  std::condition_variable m_condvar;
  ...
  };


//a.cpp
void A::func()
{
  if (condition)
  m_condvar.notify_all();
}

std::condition_variable A::getCondVar()
{
    return m_condvar;
}
...


//main.cpp
...

std::condition_variable m_condvar = A.getCondVar();
while(1){
  if (m.condvar.wait_until(uLock, timePoint) == std::cv_status::timeout){
     break;
  }
}
```

In the update code, `condition_variable` is defined within A class as a public member, so it can be accessed `A.m_condvar`.

Thanks.

Comment: Traditionally, what is _declared_ in `a.hpp` would be _defined_ in `a.cpp`.

Comment: The better way is *not using global variables*. Can't you constrain that to a source file, and have a function that helps manipulate or use it?

Comment: with the global variable all instances of `A` use the same condition variable. Is that waht you want?

Comment: The condition variable will be used in A and also the main.cpp; in A when condition reaches, condition variable will notifiy all, then in main.cpp (multithread, will run A and others), when it receives the notification, the code ends.

Comment: I wouldn't use a global. Furthermore usually the `m_` prefix would be used for non-static member variables, not for globals. I wouldn't create this variable at namespace scope, since this makes it a bit hard to tell which parts of your program are actually supposed to access the variable;IF you want to have only a single object for the whole program, I'd make it a private static variable of some class allowing you to restrict access to friends.(Better wrap the functionality the cv is supposed to be used for into a into some type though and not provide other parts of the software direct access)

Comment: Disregarding other issues, the m_condvar definition you show in main.cpp is directly before a while.  Since a while can only appear in a function, this implies to me that the definition is also inside a function. If that is the case, this would be a definition of a local variable that would be a different variable from the global you are asking for. To be global, the definition would have to be outside of any function.

Comment: Global variables using `extern` are for the most part, not needed in C++.  It still exists in C++, but there really is no reason to be using it in this day and age.  Even if you wanted to have a global, the better way to do it is to create a `class` or `struct` with a static member.

Comment: your update wont compile. You cannot copy a condition variable. Please read about [mcve] and try if your code at least compiles before posting

Comment: yes, you are right, it doesn't compile. condition_variable doesn't have a copy ctor.

Comment: @issacToo many `...` dots in your non [mcve] for my taste. VTC

Answer (score 3):

A first improvement, that is probably *needed* :

//a.hpp

```
class A
{
public:
    std::condition_variable m_condvar;
};
```

So, at least, you don't have a global object. Having a condition variable per object is better, if you want to notify/wait a single object.

If you want to notify or wait on a group of object, you should have a class for that group, and put the `condition_variable` there.

Having a full all-encompassing global is almost always bad. Check the literature on singletons and why they are an anti-pattern, to learn why.

Comment: If I define it inside A, it won't be available in the main.cpp.

Comment: or you are saying that I can have a func of getCondvar() { return m_condvar;} ?

Comment: You just need to access it through the `A` object instance. If `main` interacts with `A`s, `main` must have access to some `A`s